# Ruby On Rails Pagination and delete :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I am running into a strange situation, considering the following models:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :season, :year
    has_many :collection_items_assocs
    has_many :items, :through => :collection_items_assocs

end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :reference, :item_type_id
  has_many :pictures
  has_one :item_type

end


class CollectionItemsAssoc < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :collection_id, :item_id
   belongs_to :item
   belongs_to :collection
end
```

I can successfully retrieve Items associated to a Collection with the following code:

```
 # GET /collections/1
  # GET /collections/1.json
  def show
   @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
   @collection.items = Collection.find(params[:id]).items

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @collection.to_json(:include => {:items => @collection}) }
    end
  end
```

But when I try to include pagination (for items) like that

```
# GET /collections/1
  # GET /collections/1.json
  def show
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])

   **@collection.items = Collection.find(params[:id]).items.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page =>1)**

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @collection.to_json(:include => {:items => @collection}) }
    end
  end
```

It works for the following call

```
/retailapp/collections/1?format=json&**page=1**
```

Then if I call

```
/retailapp/collections/1?format=json&**page=2**
```

the records in the association table `CollectionItemsAssoc` are deleted

I really don't get it

Thanks for your help

Comment: Post the server log for both requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the code to fetch the items

> @collection.items = Collection.find(params[:id]).items

it assigned the fetched items to current collection object.

you need to change the response to support the pagination on associate objects

```
  def show
   @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
          format.json {
            json_hash = @collection.as_json
            json_hash[:items] = @collection.items.paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page =>1).as_json
            render json:  json_hash.to_json
            }
  end
```

Additionally you can overwrite to_json method inside Collection model.

Comment: Awesome ! works great. I am just starting ruby on rails but struggling part is the funniest